# How to send an email when the temperature is higher than 35 C?

Tags: python, email, notifications, python-3.7, sensors

I'm currently working with raspberry pi and using DHT11 to read temperature and humidity values every second. I have to send the notification to the user through email. Here're my codes that showing sensor data every second and sending email .I only need to connect these two codes that is the condition: Send mail when the temperature is higher than 35C.

```
&&& Dht_11 temperature sensor code &&&

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# read data using pin 14
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=14)

try:
while True:
result = instance.read()
if result.is_valid():
print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

print("Temperature: %-3.1f C" % result.temperature)
print("Humidity: %-3.1f %%" % result.humidity)

time.sleep(6)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("Cleanup")
GPIO.cleanup()

&&& sending email code &&&

import smtplib

smtpUser = 'youremail@gmail.com'
smtpPass = 'emailpasswd'

toAdd = 'adress@domain.com'
fromAdd = smtpUser

subject = 'RPI'
header = 'To: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject
body = 'your message'

print header + '\n' + body

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()

s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)

s.quit()
```

Comment: I have never done anything with temperatures like that before, but your temperature has a return value yes? So if your temperature has a return value, put that value in a variable. Then use a simple if statement to see if a condition on the variable is met, if it is, run s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body). For example: if my_temp > 35: s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)

Comment: @S Person D Person; thank you for all recommendation, I'll try :)